# Sum multinomials over all multi-indices with constant number of non-zero elements

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Can I find a closed form, or a simplified expression, for the following sum of multinomials
$$ \sum_{\alpha \colon |\alpha|=k,[\alpha]=l} {k \choose \alpha},$$
where $\alpha$ ranges over the multi-indices satisfying

- $|\alpha|:=\alpha_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n =k$, and
- $[\alpha]:=$ the number of non zero $\alpha_i$'s $ = l$.

**Partial answer:**
For $l=3$, we get: 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k-2} \sum_{j=1}^{k-1-i} {k\choose k-i-j,i,j} {n\choose 3} = {n\choose 3} \Big( \sum_{i=0}^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-i} {k\choose k-i-j,i,j} - 3 \sum_{i=0}^k {k\choose i} + 3\Big)$$
$$ = {n\choose 3} \Big(3^k -3 \cdot 2^k +3 \Big).$$

For $l=4$, we get:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k-3} \sum_{j=1}^{k-2-i} \sum_{p=1}^{k-1-i-j} {k \choose i,j,p,k-i-j-p} {n\choose 4}$$
$$ = {n\choose 4} \Big( \sum_{i=0}^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k-i} \sum_{p=0}^{k-i-j} {k \choose i,j,p,k-i-j-p} - 4 \sum_{j=0}^{k} \sum_{p=0}^{k-j} {k \choose j,p,k-j-p} $$
$$+ 6 \sum_{j=0}^{k} {k \choose j} - 4\Big)$$
$$={n\choose 4} \Big( 4^k - 4\cdot 3^k + 6\cdot 2^k -4 \Big).$$

Comment: For $l=1$, we get $n {k \choose k} =n$.

For $l=2$, ${n \choose 2} \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} {k \choose j} = {n \choose 2} \left( \sum_{j=0}^{k} {k \choose j} - 2 \right) = {n \choose 2} (2^k - 2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression $\sum_{\alpha \colon |\alpha|=k,[\alpha]=l} {k \choose \alpha}$
can be thought of as the number of ways $k$ (distinct) balls can be distributed into $l$ of $n$ available cells, where none of the $l$ chosen cells is empty.

Another way to think of the same problem is the number of ways to choose $l$ of $n$ available cells, times the number of surjections from a set of size $k$ to a set of size $l\leq k$ (we denote it $S_{k,l}$).

We thus have
$$\sum_{\alpha \colon |\alpha|=k,[\alpha]=l} {k \choose \alpha} = {n\choose l} S_{k,l}.$$
It can be shown, (e.g. using Inclusion Exclusion) that
$$S_{k,l} = \sum_{j=0}^{l-1} (-1)^j {l\choose j} (l-j)^k.$$
The number of surjective functions $A \to B$, where $|A|=k$ and $|B|=l$, is:

- the number of functions $A\to B$, which is $l^k$,
- minus the number of functions which "miss" a single point, ${l\choose 1}(l-1)^k$
- plus the number of functions which "miss" two points, ${l\choose 2}(l-2)^k$

etc.